# How to use Css to make CellList flow Horizontally rather than Vertically? (GWT & CSS)

Tags: css, gwt, gwtp

I have a need to use a CellList that flows horizontally, like this:

```
This is traditional celllist (showing vertically)
Page
1
2
3
....

I want it to show horizontally like this:
Page 1 2 3 ......
```

I found a solution, but some people said that this solution is not so good cos it modifies the html tag (by replacing all `<div>` to `<span>`) of the Widget.

```
public class HorizontalCellList<T> extends CellList<T> {

  public HorizontalCellList(Cell<T> cell) {
    super(cell);
  }

  @Override
  protected void renderRowValues(
      SafeHtmlBuilder sb, List<T> values, int start, SelectionModel<? super T> selectionModel) {
    SafeHtmlBuilder filteredSB = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
    super.renderRowValues(filteredSB, values, start, selectionModel);
    SafeHtml safeHtml = filteredSB.toSafeHtml();
    String filtered = safeHtml.asString().replaceAll("<div", "<span").replaceAll("div>","span>");
    sb.append(SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(filtered));
  }
}
```

Then they suggest me to use Css to achieve the same result. I tried but none of them works.

```
.horizontalCellList { display: inline; } --> it doesn't work
.horizontalCellList { display: inline; float:left; } --> it doesn't work either
myCellList.getElement().getStyle().setDisplay(Display.INLINE_BLOCK); --> doesn't work
myCellList.getElement().getElementsByTagName("li").getItem(i).getStyle().setDisplay(Display.INLINE);also doesn't work
```

For people who do not know GWT but know CSS/Html, then here is the Html code of CellList, i don't see any `<span>` there, they only have `<div>`. The trick here is how to make all the `<div>` turn to `<span>` by JUST using CSS.

```
<div class="GNOXVT5BEB" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingblur="true" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus="true">
    <div></div>
    <div>
         <div aria-hidden="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: none;">
             <div aria-hidden="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;"></div>
         </div>
         <div aria-hidden="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: none;">
              <div aria-hidden="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;">
              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone provide a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what Thomas suggested, this is a complete solution

1- myCellList.css

```
.cellListWidget {

}

.cellListEvenItem {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  zoom: 1;
}

.cellListOddItem {
  display: inline-block;    
  cursor: pointer;
  zoom: 1;
}

.cellListKeyboardSelectedItem {
  background: #ffc;
}

 @sprite .cellListSelectedItem {
  gwt-image: 'cellListSelectedBackground';
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

2- MyCellListResources.java

```
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellList;
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellList.Style;

public interface MyCellListResources extends CellList.Resources{
     @Source({"myCellList.css"})
     @Override
     public Style cellListStyle();
}
```

3- YourMainPresenter.java

```
CellList<String> myHorizontalCellList = new CellList<String>(myTextCell, GWT.<MyCellListResources> create(MyCellListResources.class));
```

The code was tested & met your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `.horizontalCellList` that you want `display: inline-block`, it's the inner `<div>` elements for each item. The selector needs to be:

```
.horizontalCellList .gwt-CellList-cellListEvenItem, .horizontalCellList .gwt-CellList-cellListOddItem
```

assuming you [`@Import`ed](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#Imported_scopes) `CellList.Style` on your `CssResource`.

(disclaimer: I only tried that in a completely re-defined custom `CellList.Style`, but there's no reason it wouldn't work with `@Import` and a *descendant* selector)

Comment: hi, can we apply "cellListEvenItem" & "cellListOddItem" style by using the Built-in Style hardcoded in Gwt such as .getElement().getStyle()....

Comment: It's not about _applying_ them (they're applied by the `CellList` itself), it's about *matching* them. Of course you could do a "manual matching" by walking the DOM looking for elements with those classe names, or using [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) but GWT doesn't expose it so you'd have to use JSNI, and it's not supported in IE8.